# How do I only output an icon to a TDBGrid field?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, tdbgrid

Using C++Builder, I have a `TDBGrid` with a column that I want to only output an icon to.   I have the icon working, but it also outputs the value. How do I disable the value from being output by default?

Here's what I do right now via the `OnDrawColumnCell` event:

```cpp
void __fastcall TMainForm::DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(TObject *Sender, const TRect &Rect,
    int DataCol, TColumn *Column, TGridDrawState State)
{
    if (DataCol==1) {
        int iconindex=Column->Field->AsInteger;
        ImageListSmall->Draw(reinterpret_cast<TDBGrid*>(Sender)->Canvas,Rect.Left+2,Rect.Top+2,iconindex,True);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`TDBGrid::DefaultDrawing`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.DefaultDrawing) property to false (that does mean, however, that you will have to draw *every* cell, not just icon cells. You can use the public [`TDBGrid::DefaultDrawColumnCell()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.DefaultDrawColumnCell) method to draw your non-icon cells).

The documentation for the [`OnDrawColumnCell`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.OnDrawColumnCell) event clearly says:

> **If DefaultDrawing is true, the data will already be drawn in the cell before the OnDrawColumnCell event**, and the grid draws a focus rectangle around selected cells after the OnDrawColumnCell event.

And the documentation for the [`DefaultDrawing`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.DefaultDrawing) property says:

> Set DefaultDrawing to true to allow the data-aware grid to draw the data in the cells of the grid automatically. **Set DefaultDrawing to false to turn off the default drawing when providing customized painting in an OnDrawColumnCell event handler** or an OnDrawDataCell event handler.
>
> When DefaultDrawing is true, the data-aware grid fetches the data for each cell from the appropriate entry in the Fields array, **and writes it to the cell**. It then draws the focus rectangle if the cell has focus, or if the cell is selected and the Options property includes dgAlwaysShowSelection.
>
> When DefaultDrawing is false, the data-aware grid draws the appropriate background color on the cell and sets up the brush and font described by the appropriate TColumn object. **However, the value of the field is not written to the cell**, and no focus rectangle is drawn.

Comment: Do you happen to know the default code used to write the cells?  Or is there a way to call back in to that function to have it handle it?

Comment: Default Drawing being off also causes the selection bar to be lost, is there another event to capture and call default handler for?

Comment: There is no other event for that, but your drawing code can call the grid's protected `DrawCellHighlight()` and `DrawCellBackground()` methods, and the Canvas's `DrawFocusRect()` method.